# How to convert json data from Poco c++ json to XML?

Tags: c++, xml, json, poco-libraries

I want to use Poco::JSON in my project to convert the received json from server to XML format for manipulation in the code . I have'nt yet tried Poco::JSON. Please provide some pointer to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a [quick implementation](https://gist.github.com/aleks-f/946d53cdf507d34e90f2) of JSON to XML handler. Use it (with caution, this is not production code) like this:

```
#include "JSON2XMLConverter.h"
#include "Poco/JSON/Parser.h"

using Poco::JSON::Parser;
using Poco::JSON::Handler;

int main()
{
    std::string json = "{ \"name\" : \"Homer\", \"age\" : 38, \"wife\" : \"Marge\", \"age\" : 36, \"children\" : [ \"Bart\", \"Lisa\", \"Maggie\" ] }";
    Handler::Ptr pJ2XConv = new JSON2XMLConverter(std::cout);
    Parser(pJ2XConv).parse(json);
    return 0;
}
```

Output (formatting added, not generated by code):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <name>Homer</name>
   <age>38</age>
   <wife>Marge</wife>
   <age>36</age>
   <children>
      <children1>Bart</children1>
      <children2>Lisa</children2>
      <children3>Maggie</children3>
   </children>
</root>
```